# Static variables becoming null

Tags: c#, .net, static-variables

I have two projects in a solution (consider them as project1 and project2). The first project (project1) contains a class that holds global variables

```
public static class GlobalTrackInfo
{
    public static string tracktitle { get; set; }
    public static Uri trackUri { get; set; }
}
```

I added a reference of project1 in project2 and set values for the static variables as follows in a class of project2

```
GlobalTrackInfo.tracktitle = "myTitle";
GlobalTrackInfo.trackUri   = new Uri("www.example.com");
```

Later I tried to access these variables in a class of project1 as

```
Title = GlobalTrackInfo.tracktitle;
```

But it appears to be null. What am I doing wrong?
Is it not possible to use global variables across different projects ?

Comment: Is your program multithreaded?

Comment: Its nearly impossible to anwer that question as we do not know where the value of that variable is set. You may either check all the locations via "Find all references" or change the field to a property and add breakpoints to the setter

Comment: no it is not multithreaded.

Comment: the variable is only set once.

Comment: Are you going to share variable between two projects?

Comment: something like that..

Comment: How about placing a breakpoint within the properties on the GlobalTrackInfo class to check if this property is being changed somewhere else. Also this will help you check if the property is set in the first place.

Comment: is project2 loaded in seperate App Domain??

Comment: the project 2 is a windows phone type project and the first project is actually of the type background audio streaming agent of windows phone

Comment: I have only one .exe and it is with the second project so they must be running in the same App Domain..

Comment: @VishnuBabu WHY? Given that project 1 is running in the streaming agent, per your own words - which I would assume has his own process/appdomain.

Comment: no the streaming agent project doesn't have an .exe and their build output is pointed to the same folder which is the bin folder of the second project

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't share a static variable between two projects while they have their own AppDomain. According to MSDN documentation:

> By default, each process using a DLL has its own instance of all the
> DLLs global and static variables..

If you want to do that it's better to use another approach such as network communication (IPC) or things like that.

Comment: I can have a DLL which is reference in another DLL....the second DLL is refernce by exe...So static varialbe in first dll will be accessible and will be live till exe is terminated...Basically static variable will be live till you have unloaded domain into which it is loaded

Comment: For a reference, see e.g. __[Application Domains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bh4z9hs.aspx)__ in the .NET Framework Development Guide on MSDN.